# Computable change in minimum word length of subgroup elements

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic

Let $G$ be an infinite finitely generated group. Fix a finite generating set for $G$.

Define $\mathrm{len}_G:G\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ by sending $g$ to the minimum length of a word in the generators and their inverses equal to $g$.

Let $H\subset G$ is an infinite finitely generated subgroup. Fix a finite generating set for $H$.

> **Question.** Under what conditions is there a computable function $m \colon \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that for all $h\in
> H$ the inequality $$ \mathrm{len}_H(h)\leq m(\mathrm{len}_G(h)) $$
> holds?

Comment: If $G$ has solvable word problem, I suspect this holds iff the membership problem in $H$ is solvable.

Comment: This is the notion of (actual) distortion function, which appears in a paper Sunik, Margolis & Meakin. @YCor's suspicion is correct, and can be strengthened slightly: if the problem of comparison of $H$-words to $G$-words is decidable in $G$, then this holds iff the membership problem in $H$ is solvable.

Comment: Specifically, it is Proposition~1.1 of [their paper](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/~margolis/papers/ams_prefix.pdf).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda thanks! I think the notion of distortion of a subgroup appears in papers by Gromov and Gersten in the early 90s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll put my comment here, so that the question has an answer.

The function $\operatorname{len}_H$ is what is called an *actual distortion function* (for $H$ in $G$) by Margolis, Meakin & Šuniḱ (see [1]). This is a notion that has been studied before in various forms in some papers by e.g. Gromov and Gersten (as @YCor points out). In their paper, MMS prove (Proposition 1.1) the rather straightforward result that as long as the problem of comparing $H$-words with $G$-words is decidable (which is no harder than the word problem for $G$), then a recursive actual distortion function for $H$ in $G$ exists if and only if the membership problem for $H$ in $G$ is decidable. The proof is very short and elementary.

[1] *Margolis, Stuart W.; Meakin, John; Šuniḱ, Zoran*, Distortion functions and the membership problem for submonoids of groups and monoids., Geometric methods in group theory. Contemporary Mathematics 372, 109-129 (2005). [ZBL1103.20049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1103.20049).